# Normal text should be separated from caption title

Tags: captions, line-breaking, text

I need to know how normal text can be separated from caption title.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb,array,arydshln}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}
Here is my problem. Formula belowe should be space-separated from normal text.
\nonumber\begin{align}
a+b+c+d+e
\end{align}
\captionof{figure}{K-Konfigurationen in Backus-Naur-Form}
This is a test. This is a test.\\
Text should be separated from caption title.\\
Test test test test test.
\end{document}
```

I will get following result:
[image]

As you can see, normal text is underneath the caption title. The distance between both should be at least 2 lines.

How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Like this: `\begin{figure*}[h]\centering
$a+b+c+d+e$
\captionof{figure}{K-Konfigurationen in Backus-Naur-Form}
\end{figure*}`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to have a non-floating `figure` environment containing math. For that you can use

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

Here is my problem. Formula below should be space-separated from normal text.

\begin{figure}[H]% ...or \begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  $\displaystyle a + b + c + d + e$
  \caption{$K$-Konfigurationen in Backus-Naur-Form}
\end{figure}

This is a test. This is a test.
Text should be separated from caption title.
Test test test test test.

\end{document}
```